# Ugly font rendering

Tags: pdftex, font-encodings, rendering

I've seen several recommendations of using T1 encoding `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`, so I did. But I did notice a difference in font rendering, and it's not prettier.

Old OT1:
[image: OT1]

T1 encoding:
[image: T1]

I know the difference seems subtle, but it's there.

Comment: Do you have a full set of fonts installed?

Comment: @JosephWright: I have no Idea.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18556/cm-clearer-than-cmsuper-after-applying-usepackaget1fontenc-fonts-get-blur

Comment: OK, I do have cm-super fonts installed.

Comment: What does pdffonts file.pdf say? Are there any type-3 fonts involved?

Comment: The final part of the log file lists all the fonts used. Also the map file loaded is listed, in braces, usually between `[1` and the closing `]` representing the shipping out of the first page. Please show these items in your question.

Comment: would \usepackage{lmodern} be the wrong thing to say here?

Comment: Here is the log file: http://fpaste.org/Fnr9/

Comment: @AymanElmasry: That's with lmodern. So the problem must be in the viewer. Which program on which OS?

Comment: Evince on Fedora 15

Comment: @Canageek lmodern solved it Thanks! Any idea why the question is off-topic? It came first on Google and your answer helped me much.