# The text in pdf is not smooth

Tags: pdftex, miktex, texstudio, text-decorations, options

I am using TeXstudio to edit Latex and create pdf files. The text is not smooth in the pdf files created by TeXstudio in my computer. When I zoom in, it will be
[image]

But if I use my friend's computer to generate the pdf files, it will be like below when I zoom in to see

[image]

Both computers have Windows 7 as OS, same Version of TeXstudio. What settings should I change to make the text smooth?

Edited:

I created two pdf files from same .tex files by TeXstudio in my and my friend's computers. The files can be downloaded in below link

https://www.sendspace.com/file/zfw5cl

Comment: I would imagine it is just a viewer issue.  If you send that document to your friend, does it look fine on his end?

Comment: No. My TeXstudio always generates the upper one no matter which computer is used to view the pdf files.

Comment: Can you upload an example pdf you made in latex some where so others can see what happens when they view it?

Comment: Well you should print a proof for see if this is only a problem on your screen or if it's also printed. But please, as @dustin asked add a full [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I’m strongly guessing you’re encountering the problem discussed at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1291/why-are-bitmap-fonts-used-automatically. Please take a look at that question as the information there might help you. If so, that's great, and we'll probably close this question as a duplicate just to keep the place tidy and to help people find answers quickly. If not, please edit your question here to explain why so that people can better focus their attention to help you.

Comment: @doncherry I have followed the steps in the link to install cm-super but the text is still blurry.  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18556/cm-clearer-than-cmsuper-after-applying-usepackaget1fontenc-fonts-get-blur In the link, it tells to use \usepackage{lmodern}. However, I don't want add \usepackage{lmodern} in my .tex files because I have tens of .tex files...

Comment: @Timespace7 Did you refresh the file name database (FNDB) in the MiKTeX settings? (For good measure, I usually also update the formats in the same menu.) As for `cm-super` vs. `lmodern`, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1390/latin-modern-vs-cm-super. `lmodern` certainly is a package which doesn’t do harm being loaded.

Comment: @doncherry Just refresh the FNDB but takes no effect.

Comment: @Timespace7 Hmm, so the package manager shows that `cm-super` is installed, but yet `\documentclass{article} \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} \begin{document} answer \end{document}` produces the jagged version of CM? Then I’m afraid I’m out of ideas; but other users, who know their way around the innards of font configuration better than I do, might be able to help you.

Comment: @Timespace7 I’m glad you found a solution! Since the underlying issue turned out to be the same as in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1291/why-are-bitmap-fonts-used-automatically, I’m voting to close this question as a duplicate. If some guide here on tex.sx that you used was missing the hint about `initexmf`, it’d be great if you could add it there as a comment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks to the helps from above, I find a solution for this.

1. Install `cm-super` package in MiKTeX

   Start -> MiKTeX folder -> Maintenance (Admin) -> Package Manager (Admin) -> Search cm-super -> Install
2. Update pdftex.map (if it doesn't take effect)

   Start Task Manager(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>) -> File -> New Task (Run...) -> Type "cmd" and hit enter -> Run command `initexmf --mkmaps`

If there is a way to use graphical user interface to update pdftex.map, please add here for those prefer GUI.

Comment: +1 for nice answer to your own question. You don't have to start Task Manager to run a command line program. Just type `cmd` in the search bar when you open the start menu (windows 7).

Answer (score -1):

It looks like your TeX-distribution might use bitmap fonts rather than postscript fonts. Postscript letters are somewhat like vector graphics, so they will scale up nicely, whereas bitmap letters can be compared to a raster image that will pixelate when scaled.

If you still want to use Computer Modern, you might try the [`ae`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/ae)-package (optionally in conjunction with the `aecompl`-package).

Comment: -1: `ae` and `aecompl` are outdated (cf. http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/l2tabu/l2tabu.pdf 2.3.9, this section is only available in German). Instead, `cm-super` or `lmodern` should be used, in conjunction with `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`.