# Problems with vector fonts and embedding

Tags: fonts, math-mode, embedding

I have written a thesis, printing on the home-printer works fine, but for publishing, there are some problems concerning the embedding and fonttypes: 
I am using Miktex via TeXnic Center on Windows 7.

My current problem: I had a non-scaleable font first, now the normal text seems to be ok, but for formulas it doens't work. 
Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[ 
   fontsize=12pt, 
   paper=a4, 
   german, 
   twoside=false 
     ]{scrbook} 

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{cmbright}
\usepackage{ae}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 


\begin{document} 

\chapter{testeins} 
aöüßLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. 

\begin{equation} 
c = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2} 
\end{equation} 

\end{document}
```

If I run this code, the formula enviroment is not a vector-font, therefore I can see the grid when I zoom in using a pdf reader. 
Analyzing it with pdffonts gives me:

```
name                                 type              emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- --- --- --- ---------
ZNESZZ+CMSSBX10                      Type 1            yes yes no       4  0
IKIYOW+CMSS12                        Type 1            yes yes no       5  0
[none]                               Type 3            yes no  no       6  0
[none]                               Type 3            yes no  no       7  0
[none]                               Type 3            yes no  no       8  0
[none]                               Type 3            yes no  no       9  0
```

For my thesis it is even more complicated. hfbright and cm-super are installed. If I remove the \usepackage{cmbright}, text and formulas are ok.

I would really appreciate your help, I am quite desparate by now...

Comment: You probably have a faulty installation of the CM-Super fonts. Try the method in http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/205641/4427

Comment: that is exactly what I thought and reinstalled cm-super. Now it works for the minimal example :) (I had to re-install as user instead of admin..no idea why). Still there are problems with not-embedded fonts in my document. Should I discuss this here or open a new post (after some trial and error on my side first)?

Comment: Don't use the package `ae`. Not doing so won't solve the problem, but it is deprecated. What does loading `lmodern` do given that you then load `cmbright`?

Comment: Use LuaTeX or XeTeX, switch to unicode and use `unicode-math`.