# The use of \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} makes my font terribly light. How to solve it?

Tags: fonts, font-encodings

I'm aware that the use of \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} is advised to prevent a lot of inconveniences on the output. However, it makes my font too light, which I confirmed by generating a pdf with the same source text without the fontenc package.

This is my preamble

```
\documentclass[10pt, oneside, twocolumn, notitlepage]{article}

\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{siunitx}
```

I use miktex on windows to compile. How do I solve it?

Sorry if I'm not presenting some relevant information or if the answer is obvious, I know nothing of the programming aspects of the typesetting system.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try loading `lmodern` (which recommended for languages with accented letters anyway) in the place of `cm-super`?

Comment: Possibly this answers your question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/205578/the-text-in-pdf-is-not-smooth

Comment: @Bernard are those packages which I should call on the preamble?

Comment: @egreg the instalation of `cm_super` as explained on the post solved my problem, thanks so much!

Comment: Yes, these packages should be installed. I'm surprised `lmodern` is not. Did you check?

Comment: @Bernard None of them were. The instalation of `cm_super` solved my problem and I just tried to install `lmodern` as you recommended but couldn't find it on the package manager.

Comment: The name of the package (in the sense of the installer, not in the LaTeX sense) is `lm`.

Comment: @Bernard just verified, it is already installed! Thanks!

Comment: Fine! The `Latin Modern` are very close to `Computer Modern` (the default) while being adapted to most European languages for a correct hyphenation.